# App restarts when woken from background

Tags: ios, background-process

G'day iOS Guru's,

I have searched extensively for an answer, but can't find one (I bet the first response to my question will be to another similar question, but I cant find it).

Anyway, my problem is that I am running a simple map app that the user can drop pins on the map with a customised circle overlay around the dropped pin.

When the app goes into the background (iphone locked or home button pressed), if I re-enter the app within ~ 5 mins, the pins are still there and the app reopens to the last screen.

All good.

However, if I leave the app in the background for longer than 5 mins, the app restarts and all the pins are lost.

I have "Application does not run in background = NO" in the plist, and also enabled "App registers for location updates" under Required background modes.

How can I prevent the app from restarting after it enters the background and load the last opened view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS can, and will, terminate your app while it's in the background if it needs additional resources to carry out whatever's going on in the foreground.

You need to ensure that your data is saved/archived when your app is terminated, and unpacked when re-launched so as to go back to where the user last was. The traditional way to do this is to use the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, which is called when your app is suspended. You can then save all the data you need in order to resume cleanly in case your app is later terminated.

However, if you're targeting iOS 6 and upwards you can take advantage of a new feature - [State Presumption & Restoration (link to documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html). State restoration off-loads some (but not all) of the heavy lifting onto iOS, and it can automatically snapshot your UI and provides easier ways to preserve and restore data.

Comment: Thanks lxt, was unaware of state presumption and restoration, sounds like that's exactly what I'm after, that link is very helpful and will give it a go.

Comment: I have put in the state preservation into my code, and when I re-open it, my annotations and overlays are restored, yay. But the map does not load, doh (basically i have my annotations and overlays visible on a plain background - no map image). What am i forgetting? I have opt-in in the app delegate, and implemented the required methods for the annotations and overlay to be encoded/decoded in the view controller. What am I missing? Oh, forgot to mention I am using storyboards, and have set the restoration id.

Comment: How are you creating the map? Just adding it in the storyboard?

Comment: Is this possible for non-story board apps?

Comment: You can use the same technique, but you will need to provide restoration methods to re-create the views from the xib files as required.

Comment: Is someone have working example of that feature, without using storyboard? it's a bit hard to find in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    // Save your data
}
```

Comment: Thanks Liolik, I had looked into that earlier, but was unsure if that was affecting the app restarting from scratch or not. I'm going to give State Presumption and restoration ago which lxt suggested below, sounds like its what I'm after. cheers.