# App restarts if re-opened from app switcher

Tags: ios, ios7, background

I have an app that is being restarted after being in the background for 10 minutes and then re-opened from the app switcher. I have a page (3rd page) that contains a textview, upon editing it. I pressed the home button and locked for 12 minutes, when I went back to the app via app switcher, the app restarts (goes back to the 1st page or is relaunched).

Is there a way to prevent this?

**EDIT:** 
Turns out the my code on the applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
_bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_bgTask];
}];
```

is causing the termination of my app in the background. any advice please?

Comment: There are plenty of existing discussions on this topic. Please do some research on this. Start with the list of related questions to the right.

Comment: I already did some research but could not find any related to my question that is why I posted this.

Comment: The very first question shown to the right under "Related" seems to cover your issue. Did the accepted answer not help you?

Comment: I see. Though the question there uses Storyboards which in mine does not, I will try to ask/discuss in that question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App restarts when woken from background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893185/app-restarts-when-woken-from-background)